# How to watch a primitive service variable in controller with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to use $watch for it. The $watch body firing at page initialization (with undefined in newValue) and not firing at "btnChangeIsLoggedIn" click.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="myApp">
<head><title>title</title></head>
<body>
    <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>

    <div ng-controller="ctrl1">
        <input type="text" ng-model="isLoggedIn" />
        <input type="button" id="btnChangeIsLoggedIn" 
            value="change logged in" ng-click="change()" />
    </div>

    <script>
        var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

        myApp.service('authService', function () {
            this.isLoggedIn = false;
        });

        myApp.controller('ctrl1', function ($scope, authService) {
            $scope.isLoggedIn = authService.isLoggedIn;

            $scope.$watch("authService.isLoggedIn", function (newValue) {
                alert("isLoggedIn changed to " + newValue);
            }, true);

            $scope.change = function() {
                authService.isLoggedIn = true;
            };
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

What I'm doing wrong?

**My code at JSFiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/googman/RA2j7/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can pass a function that will return the value of the Service's method.  Angular will then compare it to the previous value.

```
$scope.$watch(function(){
    return authService.isLoggedIn;
}, function (newValue) {
    alert("isLoggedIn changed to " + newValue);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TheSharpieOne/RA2j7/2/

Note: the reason the text field value doesn't update is because the button only changes the service's value, not the `$scope`'s  You can also get rid of that initial alert (running of the change function) but comparing the `newValue` to the oldValue and only executing the statements if they are different.

Comment: Thank you! Am I right that if I want to change the text field then I should do something like this:
`$scope.$watch(function(){
return authService.isLoggedIn;
}, function (newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue == oldValue) return;
        $scope.isLoggedIn = newValue;
        alert("isLoggedIn changed from " + oldValue + " to " + newValue);
    }, true);` (http://jsfiddle.net/googman/RA2j7/5/)

Comment: Thank you! It was killing me why my $watch on a true/false val was always returning undefined. I've used $watch on service variables before, but this was the first time with a boolean type and not a JSON object.