# How to modify HTML content based on angular controller

Tags: angularjs, single-page-application, ngroute

I am trying to build a login page and a functionality page using angularjs SPA.

```
I have following controller:
 - LoginController 
 - PredictionController

And following single page:
 - Home.html : Binded to LoginController
 - trend.html : Binded to PredictionController
 - index.html : Has no controller
```

I have navigation panel in index.html and I want to modify(add or remove) number of tabs based on login. I don't want to write navigation panel logic in each page as it is reusable. I am unable to figure out way to do this using additional controller because I am using ng-route which I guess won't allow me to use multiple controller for same page.

Here is my html code snippet for index.html:

```
<body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  </button>
                  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/">MyProject</a>

                </div>
                <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#Trend">Trend</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
            </div>
        </nav>

    <div ng-app="chartApp">
        <div ng-view></div>                         
    </div>

</body>
```

Here is the code for controller:

```
var app = angular.module('chartApp', ['ngRoute']);

    app.factory('UserVerified', function() {
        return

 {bool: false}; 
        });


    app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
        .when('/',{
            templateUrl: 'pages/home.html',
            controller: 'LoginController'
        })
        .when('/Trend', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/trend.html',
            controller: 'PredictionController'  
        })  

    });

    app.controller('LoginController', ['$scope', '$http', 'UserVerified', function($scope, $http, UserVerified){
        $scope.hasPermission = UserVerified.bool;

    $scope.getAuthentication = function(){
        console.log($scope.userId, $scope.pwd)
        $http.get('/getAuth', {
                params: { user_id: $scope.userId, pwd: $scope.pwd }
        }).success(function (response){
            console.log(response);
            UserVerified.bool = response;
            $scope.hasPermission = UserVerified.bool;
        }); 
    }

}]);
```

I'm not sure if the information is enough please edit or let me know if i'm missing some information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're going to have to move your `ng-app` directive up to the body, and create a `NavigationController` which can require your `UserVerified` factory and help maintain the state of the navigation.

You could add the `ng-controller` directive to your `navbar` explicitly, and your router should work the same.

The HTML might look something like this.

```
<body ng-app="chartApp">

    <nav ng-controller="NavigationController" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

                <!-- Only display if $scope.loggedIn -->
                <a ng-show="loggedIn" class="navbar-brand" href="#/">MyProject</a>
            </div>

            <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#Trend">Trend</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
```

**NavigationController**

```
app.controller('NavigationController', function($scope, UserVerified) {
    $scope.$watch(function() {
        return UserVerified.bool;
    }, function(state, oldState) {
        $scope.loggedIn = state;
    });
});
```

Comment: I thought of that but in that case how would the routing of pages and controller work? I will need a controller for login when login.html is loaded so in that case how will ngroute understand where to point.

Comment: I updated my answer with an example. The router should work exactly the same, it will load up the controller with on each route automatically.

Comment: Its working as per my requirement but when i log in, it doesn't makes them visible because '$scope.loggedIn' is not getting updated.

Comment: Updated code sample. You might need to add a $watcher to keep the controller in sync with the service. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21100182/3858736).